# ¿como puedo evitar que un boton submit envie muchas veces el mismo form?

Tags: javascript, django, submit, form-submit

En este caso tengo un boton submit que envia correos a varios usuarios y al hacer click comienza a cargar pero si el usuario no lo nota y pulsa mas veces el boton termina haciendo spam por que pienso en algo de JS para deshabilitar el boton una vez enviado el primer formulario

Comment: Hola @RicardoMontenegro, bienvenid@ a [so], te sugiero completar el [tour] de bienvenida para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacer que en onclick del button este se desabilite agregandolo directamente como un atributo del boton

```
<button onclick="this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();">
```

o parar el evento y controlarlo con JQuery

```
var enviado =false;
$("#bumitButton").on("click", fucntion(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 if(!enviado){
   enviado=true;
   $("#form").submit();
 }
});
```

de cualquier manera estos dependen de que tan rápido haga click el usuario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono bien